# Circular Dependency Issue

Tags: c#, wcf

I am currently trying to learn how to create a WCF service and I am facing an issue.

I have a project lets call it `MainProject` which is a console application and a second project called `SoapServer` which is created as a class library.

The `MainProject` doesn't need to reference the `SoapServer` but the `SoapServer` does need to reference stuff from within the `MainProject`.

However, even though `MainProject` doesn't need to access `SoapServer` at the moment it does so that the console application can start the host on the WCF service.

However, this obviously causes a circular dependency as I can't have MainProject refernece SoapServer and visa versa. Is there a way to get a round this.

Below is how I am opening the connection for the WCF Service.

```
public class SoapServer : ISoapServerInterface
    {

        public void startSoapServer()
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6525/hello");

            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SoapServer), baseAddress))
            {
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at: {0}", baseAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service");
                Console.ReadLine();
                host.Close();

            }
        }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Add an extra project/assembly which holds the types shared by both projects. http://java.dzone.com/articles/breaking-dependency-cycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be much code in hosting application (MainProject). It is responsible only for hosting the service and this is its sole purpose. **Don't place commonly-used code there.**

Instead **create another class library with commonly-used code and create references to it from SoapServer and from MainProject**.